# Android preferences, Device specific defaults

Tags: android, default, android-preferences

Using the Android SharedPreferences, I want to have certain preferences disabled by default on certain devices only.
I know you can use qualifiers for resources files, but there isn't a qualifier for device name or board name.

Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just, how many different defaults do you have? 2, 3, 10 or 100?

Comment: perhaps you want `Build.MODEL`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Answer (score 0):

Most of the information you seem to be looking for can be retrieved by `android.os.build`

Comment: I know about android.os.build. How do I populate the android:defaultvalue I'm the preferences XML depending on the device board name.